# how to “subscribe to yammer group by email” access option through yammer API

Tags: rest, sharepoint, yammer

I want to turn on "Subscribe to this group by email" access option for members belonging to yammer group.Is there any yammer API to achieve this?

[click here to view image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0t37P.png)

I gone through few blogs on this in google but was not much helpful

Thanks,
Maruthi

Answer (score 0):

There is no API for this. If this is important you can make feature requests on the [Yammer UserVoice](https://yammer.uservoice.com).